# Average or Any other Aggregation on multiple fields of same type in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am not able to write the request body to fetch Average Aggregations on Multiple fields in elastic search.

I have two fields field1 and field2 both are of 'double' data type. I am able to fetch the average aggregation of a single field.

This is for a single field:

```
"aggs" : {
        "AvgValuesOfField1" : {
            "avg" : {
                "field" : "field1"
            }
        }
  }
```

and for two fields (which gives an error)

```
"aggs" : {
        "AvgValuesOfField1" : {
            "avg" : {
                "field" : "field1"
            }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "AvgValuesOfField2" : {
            "avg" : {
                "field" : "field2"
            }
        }
        }
  }
```

The errors I am getting are 
"Aggregator [group_By_field1] of type [avg] cannot accept sub-aggregations"
"unable to parse BaseAggregationBuilder with name [AvgValuesOfCITempIndex]: parser not found"

The output I need is the Average of two fields separately on all documents present in the DB. 
I am using elastic DB v6.8
Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

For separate aggregations, you can do as below, you do not need to write aggs again - that's for [nested aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "AvgValuesOfField1": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    },
    "AvgValuesOfField2": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "field2"
      }
    }
  }
```